# Directional derivative of $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ exists only for $t(1,0)$ or $t(0,1)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This is a question related to the directional derivative.

I believe $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\space\text{for }(x,y)≠(0,0)$$$$f(0,0)=0$$ has a directional derivative at the point $(0,0)$ only for points $t(1,0)$ or $t(0,1)$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

How is this seen though?

I've attempted to find the directional derivative at $(0,0)$ as follows (not using unit vectors yet, but a generic vector $(x_2,y_2)\in\mathbb{R^2}$):

$$\partial_{directional}f(0,0)=\frac{f((0,0)+t(x_2,y_2))-f(0,0)}{t}=\frac{f(0+tx_2,0+ty_2)-0}{t}=\frac{\frac{tx_2ty_2}{(tx_2)^2+(ty_2)^2}}{t}=\frac{\frac{t^2(x_2y_2)}{t^2(x_2^2+y_2^2)}}{t}=\frac{x_2y_2}{t(x_2^2+y_2^2)}$$

Comment: $f$  is not even *continuous* at $(0, 0)$.

Comment: Could this be related to the fact that for the $\partial_{directional} f(0,0)$ to remain constant over any domain, it must be $\partial_{directional} f(0,0)=0$, which is possible here if only if $x_2=0$ or $y_2=0$ or both zero? The "remaining constant" is a requirement of the limit definition of the derivative (along any line)?

Comment: Any feedback on the answer? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

For a given "direction" $(x_2, y_2) \ne (0, 0)$ the function
$$
t \to \varphi(t) = f( t(x_2, y_2) ) 
$$
satisfies
$$
 \varphi(t) = \begin{cases} \frac{tx_2ty_2}{t^2x_2^2 + t^2y_2^2} = \frac{x_2y_2}{x_2^2 + y_2^2} & (t \ne 0)\\
0 & (t = 0)
\end{cases}
$$
If $x_2 \ne 0$ or $y_2 \ne 0$ then 
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \varphi(t) \ne \varphi(0)
$$
which means that $\varphi$ is not *continuous* at $t = 0$.
It follows that $\varphi$ is not *differentiable* at $t = 0$.

Therefore $f$ does not have a directional derivative at $(0, 0)$ in the
direction of $(x_2, y_2)$ if $x_2 \ne 0$ or $y_2 \ne 0$.